# Правильное регулярные выражение

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Представим, что есть строки:
'Привет, у тебя есть чит?',
'Привет, у тебя есть чит',
'Привет, пойдём сегодня читать?'.

Как бы нужно найти слово "чит" в предложениях, именно слово, а не часть другого слова как в 3 предложение выше. Кажется, что сложного?
pattern: `(.*)(чит|word1|word2|word3)(.*)`
При регулярном выражении выше во всех случаях будет совпадение. 
Я пробовал вот так: `(.*)(чит|word1|word2|word3)[\\ ]?(.*)` да и короче по разному пробовал. Но не нашёл нужный вариант.

Суть в том, что нужно найти слово\слова, перед ними обязательно должен быть(будет) пробел, а после возможно и будет, а возможно и нет. Т.е. искомое слово может быть последние в предложение, а может быть и не последние.

Регулярные выражение использую в Java.

Comment: Может требовать, чтобы предыдущый и следующий символ были не буквами? То есть заменить `(.*)` на что-нибудь вроде `(.*)[^а-яА-Я]`

Comment: Ввод текста может быть любой по символам. Я парсю игровой чат.

Comment: @Prototype-TV, граница слова - `\b` Работает ли в java, я не в курсе.

Comment: Ответы Вам уже дали, только почему-то в виде комментариев. Если «0чит123» считается за слово «чит», то используйте предложение diraria, если нет, то Visman-а. Если какой-то вариант не подходит, то объясните в чем проблема.

Comment: Я не понял как использовать \b в данном случае. Можно пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если «0чит123» считается за слово «чит», то используйте так:

```
"(.*)(чит)[^а-яА-Я](.*)" - получите отсев всех символов, которые "не буква"
```

(метод предложен участником @diraria в коментариях)

если нет, то воспользуйтесь этим предложением:

```
"\\bчит\\b" - получите отсев всех символов, которые "заканчивают слово"
```

(метод предложен участником @Visman в коментариях)

Примеры:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bчит\\b");
//Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)(чит)[^а-яА-Я](.*)");
Matcher m;

String input[] =
{ "Привет, у тебя есть чит?", "Привет, у тебя есть чит", "Привет, пойдём сегодня читать?" };
for (String text : input)
{
    m = p.matcher(text);
    boolean found = m.find();
    if (found)
    {
        System.out.println("Найдено");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Не найдено");
}
```

Результаты:

```
Найдено
Найдено
Не найдено

Найдено
Не найдено
Не найдено
```

Comment: offtopic: Почему Вы не оформляете ответы как ответы?

Comment: \\b(чит|word1|word2|word3)\\b - т.е. это позволит найти какое либо из нужных слов не учитывая что перед ними или после?

Comment: Учитывая что это слово а не его часть. "22чит22" не найдет, а "чит?" - найдет. \b означает, что могут быть знаки препинания или пробельные символы